# How to draw orthogonal lines between two points in AutoCad which will be redrawn automatically if the points are shifted?

Tags: autocad, pi-diagram

I was wondering how to do the following in AutoCAD:

Suppose we have two snap-points, say one at 0,0 and other at 100,50. I want to draw a line (or a polyline) between these two points such that (a) the legs are parallel to the axes (i.e. one leg of the line is between 0,0 and 100,0 and other between 100,0 to 100,50), and (b) if I drag the 100,50 to some other location then the line should get redrawn automatically while maintaining its legs orthogonal.

I have seen this happen in softwares built on top of AutoCAD (usually for P&ID drawing like CADWorkx), but never been able to do it in bare bones autocad.
Thanks!
Abhishek

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, autocad belongs to one of the first generations of computer *drafting* solutions, which did not cater for needs such as the one you are describing.

I think this need is cater by the later generations that try to capture the design intent, through various means (e.g. parametric feature based modelling). The progress in this domain -IMHO- coincided with the progress of solid based modelling, and as such it is more common to see these features in Solid modelling products (see Solidworks, ProEngineer, Inventor etc).

Although, I don't know of way to do what you  want (I'm out of touch with its development, because I've stopped using Autocad and its clones more than a decade ago for design work).  If I **had** to it on Autocad, I'd probably start by looking at AutoCAD macro functionality.

Comment: Well you can make autocad do this for you by enabling constraints

Comment: NMech ... Off course .. I do understand we need to probably use AutoLisp or VB, but how? I was wondering if anybody has seen any source code which can do this (like the sline command of AutoCAD plant)

Comment: Joojaa ... how?

Comment: @Abhishek http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2013/ENU/index.html?url=files/GUID-668B1B7D-9991-44CA-8607-83665A82FF7F.htm,topicNumber=d30e166397&_ga=2.151382393.1946146077.1602924606-851314039.1594465208